# Make checkout fields optional when selecting "Local Pickup" in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a code that hides unnecessary fields when choosing the "Local Pickup" delivery method.

In this case, when I select "Local Pickup" my address fields are hidden.

```
// Conditional Show hide checkout fields based on chosen shipping methods
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_field_script' );
function custom_checkout_field_script() {

    // HERE your shipping methods rate IDs
    $local_pickup = 'local_pickup:2';
    $pickpoint = 'wc_custom_shipping_pickpoint';

    $required_text = esc_attr__( 'required', 'woocommerce' );
    $required_html = '<abbr class="required" title="' . $required_text . '">*</abbr>';
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery(function($){
            var ism = 'input[name^="shipping_method"]',         ismc = ism+':checked',
                csa = 'input#ship-to-different-address-checkbox',
                rq = '-required',       vr = 'validate'+rq,     w = 'woocommerce',      wv = w+'-validated',
                iv = '-invalid',        fi = '-field',          wir = w+iv+' '+w+iv+rq+fi,
                b = '#billing_',        s = '#shipping_',       f = '_field',
                a1 = 'country',     a2 = 'address_1',   a3 = 'address_2',   a4 = 'postcode',    a5 = 'state',   a6 = 'city',
                b1 = b+a1+f,        b2 = b+a2+f,        b3 = b+a3+f,        b4 = b+a4+f,        b5 = b+a5+f,    b6 = b+a6+f,
                s1 = s+a1+f,        s2 = s+a2+f,        s3 = s+a3+f,        s4 = s+a4+f,        s5 = s+a5+f,    s6 = s+a6+f,
                pickPoint = '<?php echo $pickpoint; ?>',        localPickup = '<?php echo $local_pickup; ?>';

            // Utility function to shows or hide checkout fields
            function showHide( action='show', selector='' ){
                if( action == 'show' )
                    $(selector).show(function(){
                        $(this).addClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() == undefined )
                            $(selector+' label').append('<?php echo $required_html; ?>');
                    });
                else
                    $(selector).hide(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass(vr);
                        $(this).removeClass(wv);
                        $(this).removeClass(wir);
                        if( $(selector+' > label > abbr').html() != undefined )
                            $(selector+' label > .required').remove();
                    });
            }

            // Initializing at start after checkout init (Based on the chosen shipping method)
            setTimeout(function(){
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint ) // Chosen "Pick point" (Hiding "Delivery")
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1 ); // Country
                    showHide('hide',b2 ); // Address 1
                    showHide('hide',b3 ); // Address 2
                    showHide('hide',b4 ); // Postcode
                    showHide('hide',b5 ); // State
                    showHide('hide',b6 ); // City
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup ) // Choosen "Local pickup" (Hidding "Take away")
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);
                }
            }, 100);

            // When shipping method is changed (Live event)
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', ism, function() {
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b5);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('hide',s2);
                        showHide('hide',s3);
                        showHide('hide',s4);
                        showHide('hide',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b5);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    if( $(csa).prop('checked') ) {
                        showHide('hide',s1);
                        showHide('show',s2);
                        showHide('show',s3);
                        showHide('show',s4);
                        showHide('show',s5);
                        showHide('hide',s6);
                    }
                }
            });

            // When "shipping to different address" is changed (Live event)
            $(csa).click( function() {
                if( $(ismc).val() == pickPoint && $(this).prop('checked') )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }
                else if( $(ismc).val() == localPickup && $(this).prop('checked') )
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('hide',b2);
                    showHide('hide',b3);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b4);
                    showHide('hide',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('hide',s2);
                    showHide('hide',s3);
                    showHide('hide',s4);
                    showHide('hide',s5);
                    showHide('hide',s6);
                }
                else
                {
                    showHide('hide',b1);
                    showHide('show',b2);
                    showHide('show',b3);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b4);
                    showHide('show',b6);

                    showHide('hide',s1);
                    showHide('show',s2);
                    showHide('show',s3);
                    showHide('show',s4);
                    showHide('show',s5);
                    showHide('show',s6);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

But unfortunately, I have a problem. Address fields remain required and do not allow placing an order.

I tried to make them optional, but nothing worked.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'wc_optional_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function wc_optional_billing_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

How can I change the code so that the address fields become optional when selecting “Local Pickup”?

I will be happy for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
function custom_override_default_address_fields($address_fields) {

    $address_fields['address_1']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['address_1']['placeholder'] = '';
    $address_fields['address_2']['required'] = false;
    $address_fields['address_2']['placeholder'] = '';

return $address_fields;
}
```